# Connect Four victory check not working Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I've coded an entire program to play Connect Four, but the algorithm for checking who has won (after each turn) isn't working and I don't know why. I keep getting a weird message when I compile it (exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class connectFourDemo extends Applet
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int[][] myGrid = new int[7][6];
    // If piece is 0, white. If 1, red. If 2, black.

int xCoord, yCoord; // X and Y co-ordinates for mouse navigation.
int width, height;
int playerTurn = 1; // Player's turn. Default is 1 since red goes first.
int mx, my;  // The mouse coordinates.
boolean isButtonPressed = false;

public void init() {
    width = getSize().width;
    height = getSize().height;
    setBackground(Color.yellow);

    mx = width / 2;
    my = height / 2;     

    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);   
}

private int getXValue(int xValue) {
    if (xValue < width / 7) return 0;

    else if (xValue < width / 7 * 2) return 1;

    else if (xValue < width / 7 * 3) return 2;

    else if (xValue < width / 7 * 4) return 3;

    else if (xValue < width / 7 * 5) return 4;  

    else if (xValue < width / 7 * 6) return 5;

    else return 6;
}

private int getYValue(int yValue) {
    if (yValue < width / 6) return 0;

    else if (yValue < width / 6 * 2) return 1;

    else if (yValue < width / 6 * 3) return 2;

    else if (yValue < width / 6 * 4) return 3;

    else if (yValue < width / 6 * 5) return 4;  

    else return 5;
}

public void verticalCheck(int x, int y) {
    if (myGrid[x][y] == 1) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (myGrid[xCoord][i] == 1) {
                System.out.println("Counter one in vertical check is " + counter + ".");
                if (myGrid[xCoord][i - 1] == 1 && (i - 1 >= 0)) counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 has won Connect Four vertically!");
        }
    }

    else if (myGrid[x][y] == 2) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (myGrid[xCoord][i] == 2) {
                System.out.println("Counter two in vertical check is " + counter + ".");
                if (myGrid[xCoord][i - 1] == 2 && (i - 1 >= 0)) counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 has won Connect Four vertically!");
        }
    }
}

public void horizontalCheck(int x, int y) {
    if (myGrid[x][y] == 1) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            if (myGrid[i][y] == 1) {
                System.out.println("Counter one in horizontal check is " + counter + ".");
                if (myGrid[i + 1][y] == 1 && (i + 1 <= 6)) counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 has won Connect Four horizontally!");
        }           
    }

    else if (myGrid[x][y] == 2) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            if (myGrid[i][y] == 2) {
                System.out.println("Counter two in horizontal check is " + counter + ".");
                if (myGrid[i + 1][y] == 2 && (i + 1 <= 6)) counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 has won Connect Four horizontally!");
        }
    }
}

public void diagonalCheckRight(int x, int y) {
    if (myGrid[x][y] == 1) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 5; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (myGrid[i][j] == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Counter one in diagonal check right is " + counter + ".");
                    if (myGrid[i + 1][j + 1] == 1 && (i + 1 <= 6) && (j + 1 <= 5)) counter++;
                    else if (myGrid[i - 1][j + 1] == 1 && (i - 1 >= 0) && (j + 1 <= 5)) counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 has won Connect Four diagonally!");
        }
    }

    else if (myGrid[x][y] == 2) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (myGrid[i][j] == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Counter two in diagonal check right is " + counter + ".");
                    if (myGrid[i + 1][j + 1] == 1 && (i + 1 <= 6) && (j + 1 <= 5)) counter++;
                    else if (myGrid[i - 1][j + 1] == 1 && (i - 1 >= 0) && (j + 1 <= 5)) counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 has won Connect Four diagonally!");
        }
    }
}

public void diagonalCheckLeft(int x, int y) {
    if (myGrid[x][y] == 1) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (myGrid[i][j] == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Counter one in diagonal check left is " + counter + ".");
                    if (myGrid[i - 1][j - 1] == 1 && (i + 1 <= 6) && (j - 1 >= 0)) counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 has won Connect Four diagonally!");
        }
    }

    else if (myGrid[x][y] == 2) {
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (myGrid[i][j] == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Counter one in diagonal check left is " + counter + ".");
                    if (myGrid[i - 1][j - 1] == 2 && (i <= 6) && (j >= 0)) counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 has won Connect Four diagonally!");
        }
    }
}

public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {
    // Called when the pointer enters the applet's rectangular area.
}

public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {
    // Called when the pointer leaves the applet's rectangular area.
}

public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
    // Called after a press and release of a mouse button with no motion in between.

    mx = e.getX();
    my = e.getY();

    xCoord = getXValue(mx);
    yCoord = getYValue(my);

    if (myGrid[xCoord][yCoord] == 0 && playerTurn == 1) { // Drop from top, fall to bottom and vice versa.
        for (int y = 5; y >= yCoord; y--) {
            if (myGrid[xCoord][y] == 0) {
                myGrid[xCoord][y] = 1;
                y = yCoord - 1;
            }
        }

        verticalCheck(xCoord, yCoord);
        horizontalCheck(xCoord, yCoord);
        diagonalCheckRight(xCoord, yCoord);
        diagonalCheckLeft(xCoord, yCoord);

        playerTurn = 2;
    }

    else if (myGrid[xCoord][yCoord] == 0 && playerTurn == 2) {          
        for (int y = 5; y >= yCoord; y--) {
            if (myGrid[xCoord][y] == 0) {
                myGrid[xCoord][y] = 2;
                y = yCoord - 1;
            }
        }  

        verticalCheck(xCoord, yCoord);
        horizontalCheck(xCoord, yCoord);
        diagonalCheckRight(xCoord, yCoord);
        diagonalCheckLeft(xCoord, yCoord);

        playerTurn = 1;
    }
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {  // Called after a button is pressed down.
    repaint();
    // "Consume" the event so it won't be processed in the
    // default manner by the source which generated it.
    e.consume();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {  // Called after a button is released.
    repaint();
    e.consume();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {  // Called during motion when no buttons are down.
    mx = e.getX();
    my = e.getY();

    mx = mx / 50; // Divides applet width by the width of each oval (50).
    my = my / 50; // Divides applet height by the height of each oval (50).

    showStatus("Mouse in column " + (mx + 1) + ", row " + (my + 1) + ".");
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {  // Called during motion with buttons down.
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
   for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            if (myGrid[x][y] == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
            }

            if (myGrid[x][y] == 1) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
            }

            if (myGrid[x][y] == 2) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }

            g.fillOval((width / 7) * x + 2, (height / 6) * y + 1, (width / 7) - 4, (height / 6) - 4);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know what that error generally means?

Comment: Can you tell us on which line this happens? Because it could be anytime you do myGrid[x][y] and there are a lot of those.

Comment: Not a weird exception, its name explains itself.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? If so you have a debugger you should use and step through it. I'm not going to go through all that code. It's very bulky and I'm sure could be written better using recursion or with better organized loops so there aren't that many branches.

Comment: @Borgleader This is the copypaste of the debug console:

connectFourDemo [Java Applet] 
 sun.applet.AppletViewer at localhost:58589 
  Thread [AWT-Shutdown] (Running) 
  Daemon Thread [AWT-Windows] (Running) 
  Thread [thread applet-connectFourDemo.class] (Running) 
  Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running) 
  Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running) 
  Thread [AWT-EventQueue-1] (Suspended (exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)) 
   EventDispatchThread.run() line: not available 
  Thread [AWT-EventQueue-1] (Running) 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe (2012-09-20 2:02:38 PM)

Comment: @BSull Yes I'm using Eclipse. This is a class assignment and I've just started the semester using Eclipse, so I'm not experienced in what I should/shouldn't use with regards to debuggers/IDEs.

Comment: Use the debug feature and step through your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran the code, your problem is in "diagonalCheckRight", namely this section:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 5; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (myGrid[i][j] == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Counter one in diagonal check right is " + counter + ".");
                    if (myGrid[i + 1][j + 1] == 1 && (i + 1 <= 6) && (j + 1 <= 5)) counter++;
                    else if (myGrid[i - 1][j + 1] == 1 && (i - 1 >= 0) && (j + 1 <= 5)) counter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Your `j` index starts at 5, in the if you do `myGrid[i+1][j+1]` so that means on the first iteration you're accessing `myGrid[1][6]`, however you defined `myGrid` to be of size `[7][6]` and so you're out of bounds because the valid indices are: [0..6][0..5].

Also next time look at the error message, my console was showing:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at Main.diagonalCheckRight(Main.java:134)

I renamed the class to Main, and that 134 is exactly the line number where I found the error.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tampered with it a bit, fixing the loop and it works fine now.